# dispatch_barrier_async not word with dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

There are my code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("zxc", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"1");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"3");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"4");
});
dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"write");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"5");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"2");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"7");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"6");
});
```

`dispatch_barrier_async` does not work with `dispatch_get_global_queue` but can work with `dispatch_queue_create("zxc", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);`

Why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? What is the actual issue? Be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. You cannot put a barrier on a global queue. You can only put barriers on private queues you create yourself. As explained in the documentation for `dispatch_barrier_async`:

> The queue you specify should be a concurrent queue that you create yourself using the dispatch_queue_create function. If the queue you pass to this function is a serial queue or one of the global concurrent queues, this function behaves like the dispatch_async function.